# How do I iterate over a xml file recursively and access the child nodes/elements and store their data using Python?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have a XML file like below. Now I need to access `port->name`, `port->wire->direction`, `port->wire->driver->defval`. The XML file is very large in size.

How do I approach this?

```
<spirit:Bus> 
    <spirit:Ports>   
        <spirit:port>
            <spirit:name>ABCPORT</spirit:name>
            <spirit:description>SOME DESCRIPTION</spirit:description>
            <spirit:wire>
                <spirit:direction>INPUT</spirit:direction>
                <spirit:driver>
                    <spirit:defaultValue>0</spirit:defaultValue>
                </spirit:driver>
            </spirit:wire>
        </spirit:port>
        <spirit:port>
            <spirit:name>PQRPORT</spirit:name>
            <spirit:description>SOME DESCRIPTION</spirit:description>
            <spirit:wire>
                <spirit:direction>OUTPUT</spirit:direction>
            </spirit:wire>
        </spirit:port>        
    </spirit:ports>
</spirit:Bus>
```

Comment: ```ElementTree``` is in the standard library. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html. If you have questions how to use it, post your problem along with the code you've tried.

Comment: Is your desired output `0`?

Comment: I want something like - Port-ABCPORT, Direction-Input,Default value-0;Port-PQRPORT, Direction-Output.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to address this is with lxml and xpath:

```
from lxml import etree

#the xml below is somewhat different than the one in the question, because of a type and the declare namespaces

spirit = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc xmlns:spirit="http://example.com">
   <spirit:Bus>
      <spirit:Ports>
         <spirit:port>
            <spirit:name>ABCPORT</spirit:name>
            <spirit:description>SOME DESCRIPTION</spirit:description>
            <spirit:wire>
               <spirit:direction>INPUT</spirit:direction>
               <spirit:driver>
                  <spirit:defaultValue>0</spirit:defaultValue>
               </spirit:driver>
            </spirit:wire>
         </spirit:port>
         <spirit:port>
            <spirit:name>PQRPORT</spirit:name>
            <spirit:description>SOME DESCRIPTION</spirit:description>
            <spirit:wire>
               <spirit:direction>OUTPUT</spirit:direction>
            </spirit:wire>
         </spirit:port>
      </spirit:Ports>
   </spirit:Bus>
</doc>
"""

doc = etree.XML(spirit.encode('utf-8'))
ports = doc.xpath('//*[local-name()="port"]')
for port in ports:
    try:
        print("Port-",port.xpath('.//*[local-name()="name"]')[0].text)
        print("Direction",port.xpath('.//*[local-name()="direction"]')[0].text)
        print("Default value",port.xpath('.//*[local-name()="defaultValue"]')[0].text)
    except:
        continue
```

Output:

```
Port- ABCPORT
Direction INPUT
Default value 0
Port- PQRPORT
Direction OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 0):

To have properly formatted XML, I added the namespace to your sample:

```
<spirit:Bus xmlns:spirit="http://dummy.com">
    ...
</spirit:Bus>
```

but *Bus* is still the root node, as in your sample.
Of course, you can change the given URL to whatever you wish.

To do your task solely in *ElementTree* you can use the following code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

tree = et.parse('Input.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
ns = {'spirit': 'http://dummy.com'}
for nd in root.findall('spirit:Ports/spirit:port', ns):
    print(nd.tag.split('}')[1], nd.findtext('spirit:name', namespaces=ns),
        nd.findtext('spirit:wire/spirit:direction', namespaces=ns),
        nd.findtext('spirit:wire/spirit:driver/spirit:defaultValue', namespaces=ns))
```

Note that your XML contains a namespace specification, so you have also
to specify it in the code.

My code shows also how to get the **local** name of a node (without the namespace).

The result, for your sample is:

```
port ABCPORT INPUT 0
port PQRPORT OUTPUT None
```